# Laravel: Input old for radio button

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I want to insert Input::old with my radio buttons

```
<td>{{ Form::radio('student['.$user->student_id.'][status]', 'present', (Input::old('student') == 'present')) }}</td>
<td>{{ Form::radio('student['.$user->student_id.'][status]', 'late', (Input::old('student') == 'late')) }}</td>
<td>{{ Form::radio('student['.$user->student_id.'][status]', 'absent', (Input::old('student') == 'absent'))  }}</td>
<td>{{ Form::radio('student['.$user->student_id.'][status]', 'others', (Input::old('student') == 'others'))  }}</td>
```

I tried this and it doesn't work :(  Please help

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? I think Input::old('student') will contain an array of students ids, so i don't think you can use it this way.

Comment: sorry... is there any other way on how to do this method?

Comment: Not sure, but you can try Input::old('student.'.$user->student_id.'.status')

Comment: i tried it...but when i go to it again... it doesnt show a checked radio button :(

Answer (score 1):

**Try like this**

```
{{ Form::radio('student', 'present', (Input::old('student') == 'present'), array('id'=>'present', 'class'=>'radio')) }}
```